# SED remove everything before string

Tags: bash, sed

I have a plain Mail and i need to remove everything before `Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours`
 i thought it would work best with sed.

I searched the internet but there it's just with a delimiter or something similar.

You have any ideas?

Part of the Mail:

```
...(Personal Part of the Email)...
...
The following clients have no associated schedule
NodeDomainContact
-KABA-FILESYSTEM-
-USTICA-FILESYSTEM-

Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours
DomainNodenamePlatformTypeActivityData amountElapse timeAffectedFailedMedia     wait
-FILESYSTEM-ABSYNTHE-Linux x86-64-XFS-
BACKUP-
337.5 MB-
00:00-
60-
0-
0
...
```

Desired Output:

```
Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours
DomainNodenamePlatformTypeActivityData amountElapse timeAffectedFailedMedia     wait
-FILESYSTEM-ABSYNTHE-Linux x86-64-XFS-
BACKUP-
337.5 MB-
00:00-
60-
0-
0
...
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '/Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours/{p=1}p' file
```

Or sed:

```
sed -n '/Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours/,$p' file
```

Test with your email example with awk (sed cmd above has same output):

```
kent$  cat f
...(Personal Part of the Email)...
...
The following clients have no associated schedule
NodeDomainContact
-KABA-FILESYSTEM-
-USTICA-FILESYSTEM-

Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours
DomainNodenamePlatformTypeActivityData amountElapse timeAffectedFailedMedia     wait
-FILESYSTEM-ABSYNTHE-Linux x86-64-XFS-
BACKUP-
337.5 MB-
00:00-
60-
0-
0
...

kent$  awk '/Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours/{p=1}p' f
Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours
DomainNodenamePlatformTypeActivityData amountElapse timeAffectedFailedMedia     wait
-FILESYSTEM-ABSYNTHE-Linux x86-64-XFS-
BACKUP-
337.5 MB-
00:00-
60-
0-
0
..
```

Comment: @Damon interesting, I tested here again with the sed, it works.. :-(  `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: 4.2.1, maybe did something wrong on my side but it works, that's what matters

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed address range to not print all lines from first to the pattern as

```
$ sed -n '1, /Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours/!p;
DomainNodenamePlatformTypeActivityData amountElapse timeAffectedFailedMedia     wait
-FILESYSTEM-ABSYNTHE-Linux x86-64-XFS-
BACKUP-
337.5 MB-
00:00-
60-
0-
0
...
```

---

To include the `Summary...` line as well,

```
$ sed -n '1, /Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours/!p; /Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours/p' test
Summary of client activity for the last 24 hours
DomainNodenamePlatformTypeActivityData amountElapse timeAffectedFailedMedia     wait
-FILESYSTEM-ABSYNTHE-Linux x86-64-XFS-
BACKUP-
337.5 MB-
00:00-
60-
0-
0
...
```